# Tracking researchers' affiliations

Tags: research-process, affiliation

I am currently trying to investigate whether the CJEU verdict Brüstle vs. Greenpeace in 2011 prompted EU researchers to search for employment abroad. For that, I want to track researchers affiliation history over the years. I have already identified a suitable set of researchers from Scopus using

TITLE-ABS-KEY ( "human embryonic stem cell*" )  AND  DOCTYPE ( ar )  AND  PUBYEAR  <  2010  AND  PUBYEAR  >  1997  AND  ( AFFILCOUNTRY ( belgium )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( bulgaria )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( denmark )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( germany )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( estonia )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( finland )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( france )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( greece )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( ireland )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( italy )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( croatia )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( latvia )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( lithuania )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( luxembourg )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( malta )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( netherlands )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( austria )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( poland )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( portugal )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( romania )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( slovakia )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( slovenia )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( spain )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( sweden )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( czechia )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( hungary )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( united  AND kingdom )  OR  AFFILCOUNTRY ( cyprus ) )

With that search query, I am hoping to find the researchers that were the most active in the EU in the first decade of the 21st century. Now, I would like to track their affiliation history over the years to for example see if one researcher from Sweden would be prompted to go to Israel or the US where patent regulations are different. However, Scopus does not give me this information in a format where I can explicitly link research activity in one year to my researcher and to one specific affiliation. Does anyone know a tool to conduct this kind of query? I have planned to analyze the data in RStudio afterwards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about academia, but about programming for data analysis.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I disagree, the question boils down to: Is there a database of (past and present) author affiliations? (That might be off-topic as a shopping question, but it isn't about programming nor data analysis.)

Comment: I wonder if it is even possible to reliably link research activity of a given researcher in one year to *one specific* affiliation? People often have multiple simultaneous affiliations, move mid-year, put both past and current affiliation on works spanning both employment periods, and so on. And I believe Scopus only extracts affiliations from papers, so you may miss parts of someone's affiliation history if they don't manage to publish while at a certain affiliation.

Comment: @Anyon so far I have used the respective affiliation that was listed in Scopus as per publication. I realize that this might not be the best way to track the affiliation history of scientists, but lacking other meaningful parameters I went with what I had. The problem here is that Scopus exports the data in a very weird way. On the one hand, you have scientists that are clearly associated with one specific institution, on the other hand, sometimes Scopus groups all scientists together in one cell. It's really inconsistent and impossible to work with at this stage...

Comment: Well now that you have put my question on hold, could you kindly tell me as to a more appropriate place where I can post this question? Thanks!